# Add row top of my data datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have readed data from SQL in my DataGrid WPF

Customers | CustName
   1      | Pesho
   2      | Gosho
   3      | Tosho

Now I want programmatically to add one Row which to be TOP of all others data.

Customers | CustName
   0      | THIS IS TOP ROW  //HERE
   1      | Pesho
   2      | Gosho
   3      | Tosho

With this code I load my data at the begining from SQL

```
        `string CmdString = string.Empty;
        using (conn)
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT top 10 * FROM Customers";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Customers");
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

        }`
```

Comment: You can not add a row with id 0 before a row with id 1.

Comment: I want TextBox or Combo for example

Comment: Your question is unclear because our context may be different. Please explain your question a bit more.

Comment: I want to add one row with comboBox for example as first row and to use this combo to filtering my data in the grid. This combo will be filled at the begining with data from the grid and when the user select any value from there I will filtering my DataGrid

Comment: Why not adding the ComboBox outside the DataGrid? That would be a much cleaner way. 
And to be honest: you should get familiar with the MVVM pattern when building WPF applications.